# How to enable automatically colorize the output of tree without using -C flag in bash all the time?

Tags: bash, colors, tree

I am tired of using the `-C` with the `tree` all the time. I would like to tweak the `tree` to colorize files and directories to its automatic behavior so that I don't have to type the -C flag all the time.

How to enable automatically colorize the output of tree without using -C flag in bash all the time?

Comment: Run `alias tree='tree -C'`.  For man information, see `help alias`.   To make this change permanent, put it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: first thank you so much. Secondly, when I rebooted the system the ~/.bashrc deleted all the previous aliases too. Thirdly, when I change to su tree command no long works. The tree command says invalid argument but the same tree command works in the regular user john

Comment: A)  Whenever you reboot, you will have only the aliases defined by the configuration files (such as `~/.bashrc`).  Put whatever aliases you want to keep in those files.  B)  Also run `alias sutree=su tree -C` and then run `sutree` when you want `su tree -C`.  (Did you mean `sudo tree`?)

Comment: really appreciate your help sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "alias tree='tree -C'" >>/etc/profile.d/tree-C.sh`  Then logout and log back in.  Putting it in /etc/profile.d makes this shortcut available to all users on the machine so that it'll work even if you change user accounts (`su`/`sudo`)

Comment: thank you so much it worked i really appreciate your help